# What is the signature format for metadata on generic methods in .NET 2.0/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

For instance, parameters in a method that use the `out` keyword in C# will show up in the metadata signature preceded by an ampersand `&`. I'm trying to create the signature for a generic method but I don't want to use the metadata APIs to figure this out, surely it's documented somewhere?

Here's an example of what I mean for BeginReceiveFrom on the Socket class:

```
        System.IAsyncResult([]System.Byte,System.Int32,System.Int32,
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags,&System.Net.EndPoint,
System.AsyncCallback,System.Object)
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a backtick followed by the number of arguments, for the unconstructed type, e.g.

```
List`1
Dictionary`2
```

From ECMA 335, [section 10.7.2:](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)

> **10.7.2 Type names and arity encoding**
>
> CLS-compliant generic type names are encoded using the format *“name[`arity]”*, where […] indicates that the grave accent character “`” and *arity* together are optional. The encoded name shall follow these rules:
>
> 1. *name* shall be an *ID* (see Partition II) that does not contain the “`” character.
> 2. *arity* is specified as an unsigned decimal number without leading zeros or spaces.
> 3. For a normal generic type, *arity* is the number of type parameters declared on the type.
> 4. For a nested generic type, *arity* is the number of newly introduced type
>      parameters.

Not sure about constructed types...

Answer (score 2):

To declare a generic method you use `!!T` to refer to the generic parameters:

```
.method public static void Method<T1, T2>(!!T1 arg1, !!T2 arg2) {
    // ...
}
```

or you can use their number:

```
.method public static void Method<T1, T2>(!!0 arg1, !!1 arg2)
```

and to call a generic method you provide the instantiation. However, the types referred to in the instantiation are wrt the the *called method*, not where you're calling it from:

```
ldc.i4.1
newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()

// !!0 and !!1 refer to the generic parameters of Method<T1, T2>,
// not any generic method this call instruction is part of
call void Method<int32, object>(!!0,!!1)
```

If the method is part of a generic type, you specify the type instantiation using `!T` to refer to the type parameters in a similar fashion. Note that it is a convention that generic types have a ` after the type name, followed by the number of generic arguments:

```
call instance void MyGenericType`1<int32>::Method(!0)
```